Can the characteristic function $\chi_\rho(\beta)={\rm tr}[\rho D(\beta)]$ be an indicator function?
Given the characteristic function defined as:
$$\chi(\beta)=\text{tr}[\rho D(\beta)],$$
with $D(\alpha)=e^{\alpha a^\dagger-\bar\alpha a}$ the displacement operator. Is it possible that for some $\rho$ we have
$$\chi(\beta)=\textbf{1}_A,$$
for $\textbf{1}_A$ the indicator function of some area $A$ in phase-space?

I'd guess not? Consider that the Wigner at $\alpha=0$ reads $W(0)=\frac1{\pi^2}\int d^2\eta\chi(\eta)=|A|/\pi^2$, and so for large enough $A$ the Wigner wouldn't be normalised

Actually it is normalized given that the integral of the Wigner in all its domain is exactly the value of the characteristic function at 0, so as far as the area contains the 0 is normalized.

There would be a limit to the size of $A$, because that maximum amplitude of a Wigner function is bounded.
